# What is the EU definition of a small part for children under 3?

Tags: european-union, minor, product-liability

I am searching for test on small parts for children under 3 years. I found the definition for the US (see below) but not for the EU. Page 87 of the [Explanatory Guidance Document to Toy Safety Directive 2009/48/EC](http://ec.europa.eu/DocsRoom/documents/4208/attachments/1/translations/en/renditions/native) mentions:

> This means that like the toys under point 4 (d), the packaging needs to pass the small parts test cylinder test 8.2 in EN 71-1:2011.

I found [this page](http://ec.europa.eu/growth/single-market/european-standards/harmonised-standards/toys_is) that mentions "EN 71-1:2011", but has no link.

How can I find the EU definition of a small part for children under 3?

**For the US**: I found [this page from the US Consumer Product Safety Commission](https://www.cpsc.gov/Business--Manufacturing/Business-Education/Business-Guidance/Small-Parts-for-Toys-and-Childrens-Products/):

> A small part is any object that fits completely into a specially designed test cylinder 2.25 inches long by 1.25 inches wide that approximates the size of the fully expanded throat of a child under three years old.
>
> ...
>
> If a small part fits completely into the cylinder, and the toy or product from which it came is intended for use by children under three, the toy or product is banned because the small part presents a choking hazard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quote from the directive looks like it points to the specification you have in mind.

EU directives are usually freely available, but EN standards are subject to copyright and are normally purchased from the Standards Organisation that issues them - this is how preparation of standards is funded.

Purchasing a copy of the standard would be the recommended way to proceed, and the latest version of EN71-1:2014+A1:2018 is available [here](https://shop.bsigroup.com/ProductDetail?pid=000000000030318992) (BSi is the Organisation in the UK, other Organisations exist for other countries).

There are some sites that "share" standards, but these may not have the latest version or be otherwise unreliable, and might disappear and/or be subject to legal action if Standards Organisations chose to enforce copyright. I'll mention [this example](https://law.resource.org/pub/eu/toys/en.71.1.2014.html) purely to demonstrate that such sites exist.

Comment: Well done! As of this writing, the BSI sells the specification for £330.